# is it possible to search firefox cache memory and disk cache

Tags: firefox, caching, mozilla

is it some how possible to search firefox cache entries from an application which is online and doesn't ask user to install anything on his computer...does mozilla provide any api for this or some functions to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the cache you want, maybe something more along the line of 
HTML5 [local storage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/) or [Offline Web Application](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/offline.html#offline), apart from that it would be difficult to know what is in the entire cache due to security constrains, but you can use the server response header to detect what item the browser think it has in cache (detect the response 304 in http server header, if you provide the proper headers ).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the local cache is available online from any other computer, but you can type `about:cache` in the URL bar and it'll take you to a page that can identify things in both memory and disk.

Hope that helps.

Comment: i know about that about:cache method thanks for that.i am asking the cross application thing..not from firefox but from other application.